# Having trouble adjusting CSS value dynamically within a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have this jQuery animated banner, and I want the small scrolling words to be vertically centered with the large word "one", regardless of browser width. It initially works due to the media queries I set up in the CSS, but if you resize the browser window, the alignment gets messed up. How can I modify the code so the value of textTop gets updated on window resize? I tried wrapping the contents of the startSlider function with `$(window).on('resize', function(){...})` but that didn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  startSlider(0);

  function startSlider(index) {
    var textTop = $('.descriptor').css('top');
    $('#feedback').text('textTop = ' + textTop);
    var $img = $('#hp-animation div img').eq(index);
    var $descriptor = $('#hp-animation div span.descriptor').eq(index);

    $img.fadeIn(1000);
    $descriptor.show().animate({
      top: '-=50px',
      opacity: 1
    }, 1000, 'easeOutQuad', function() {

      $(this).delay(2000).animate({
        top: '-=50px',
        opacity: 0
      }, 500, 'easeOutQuad', function() {
        $(this).hide().css('top', textTop);
      });

      $img.delay(2000).fadeOut(600, function() { /* It seems that the speed here needs to be greater than the speed of the above animation; otherwise, the value of textTop is set before the animation is finished. */
        if ($('#hp-animation div img').length - 1 == index) startSlider(0);
        else startSlider(index + 1);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#hp-animation {
  height: 500px;
  background: #e6eaed;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#hp-animation #big-one {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18em;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #f05c23;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 46%;
  top: 70px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#hp-animation img,
#hp-animation .descriptor {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#hp-animation img {
  left: 50%;
  opacity: .25;
  z-index: 1;
}

#hp-animation .descriptor {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1;
  left: 58%;
  top: 275px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #394349;
  z-index: 2;
}

#feedback {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 959px) {
  #hp-animation {
    height: 400px;
  }
  #hp-animation #big-one {
    font-size: 15em;
    top: 60px;
  }
  #hp-animation img {
    height: 400px;
  }
  #hp-animation .descriptor {
    top: 230px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #hp-animation {
    height: 300px;
  }
  #hp-animation #big-one {
    font-size: 10em;
    top: 55px;
    right: 50%;
  }
  #hp-animation img {
    height: 300px;
  }
  #hp-animation .descriptor {
    top: 180px;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #hp-animation {
    height: 200px;
  }
  #hp-animation #big-one {
    font-size: 6em;
    top: 42px;
    right: 54%;
    letter-spacing: -10px;
  }
  #hp-animation img {
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
  }
  #hp-animation .descriptor {
    top: 135px;
    left: 55%;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.easing/1.3/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<div id="hp-animation">
  <p id="big-one">one</p>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-partner.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Partner</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-standard.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Standard</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-platform.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Platform</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-invoice.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Invoice</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-solution.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Solution</span>
  </div>

  <div id="feedback"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't see any issue in your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif the issue is that the text is not centered vertically when it animates.

Comment: yes but when am trying it's fine for me ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before that wrecked my head. I couldn't figure out a way to use `.resize` in conjunction with a time delay loop. What I ended up doing was something similar to what I have done below. Basically, I've used classes and css to perform the animations rather than jQuery. So all I'm doing is adding and removing classes and then using css to do the rest.

This actually looks like a good scenario for css keyframes too which might be worth looking in to.

Hope that helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 2; 
  startSlider();
  setTimeout(function() {
      $('#hp-animation>div:nth-of-type(1)').addClass('active');
  }, 1000);
  
  function startSlider() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var next = counter == 1 ? 5 : counter - 1;
 var descriptor = $('#hp-animation>div:nth-of-type(' +  counter + ')');
 var next = $('#hp-animation>div:nth-of-type(' +  next + ')');
 var other_descriptors = $('#hp-animation>div');
 
 //remove classes
 other_descriptors.removeClass('active next');
 
 //add classes
 next.addClass('next');
 descriptor.addClass('active');
    startSlider();
 if(counter<5){
  counter++;
 }else{
  counter=1;
 }
 return counter;
 }, 5000);

}
});
```

```css
#hp-animation .next .descriptor {
    top: 175px;
}
#hp-animation .active .descriptor {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 225px;
}
#hp-animation .active img {
 opacity:0.25;
}
#hp-animation img , #hp-animation .descriptor{
 transition: 0.5s ease;
 -webkit-transition:  0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition:  0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition:  0.5s ease; 
  -o-transition:  0.5s ease;

}
#hp-animation {
  height: 500px;
  background: #e6eaed;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#hp-animation #big-one {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18em;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #f05c23;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 46%;
  top: 70px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#hp-animation img,
#hp-animation .descriptor {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#hp-animation img {
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#hp-animation .descriptor {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1;
  left: 58%;
  top: 275px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #394349;
  z-index: 2;
}

#feedback {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 959px) {
#hp-animation .next .descriptor{
    top: 130px;
}
#hp-animation .active .descriptor {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 180px;
}
  #hp-animation {
    height: 400px;
  }
  #hp-animation #big-one {
    font-size: 15em;
    top: 60px;
  }
  #hp-animation img {
    height: 400px;
  }
  #hp-animation .descriptor {
    top: 230px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
#hp-animation .next .descriptor {
    top: 80px;
}
#hp-animation .active .descriptor {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 130px;
}
  #hp-animation {
    height: 300px;
  }
  #hp-animation #big-one {
    font-size: 10em;
    top: 55px;
    right: 50%;
  }
  #hp-animation img {
    height: 300px;
  }
  #hp-animation .descriptor {
    top: 180px;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #hp-animation {
    height: 200px;
  }
  #hp-animation #big-one {
    font-size: 6em;
    top: 42px;
    right: 54%;
    letter-spacing: -10px;
  }
  #hp-animation img {
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
  }
  #hp-animation .descriptor {
    top: 135px;
    left: 55%;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hp-animation">
  <p id="big-one">one</p>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-partner.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Partner</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-standard.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Standard</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-platform.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Platform</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-invoice.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Invoice</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/link-animation/icon-one-solution.png">
    <span class="descriptor">Solution</span>
  </div>

  <div id="feedback"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, Derek. Thank you for all the effort you put into this. I noticed a couple of issues. First, the final descriptor slides down instead of up. I fixed this by replacing the declaration of next with var next = counter == 1 ? 5 : counter - 1;  Second, is there any way to make the animation play immediately, instead of having to wait five seconds?

Comment: @KrisHunt Nice fix. It was no trouble at all... and by that I mean I completely chased the rabbit down the hole! There is indeed a way to make it play immediately. I'll update my answer. I'm basically going to set another timeout to fire after one second and add the active class to the first div. Will then need to set counter to 2 instead of 1. Could just add the class straight into the html but doing it this way will make it look a little smoother.